# How to remove Zbippirad.info message?

Tags: safari

I have a MacBook Air. Whilst using Safari the message

> warning: install www.zbippirad.info to continue

has appeared. Now I cannot do anything with Safari on that user profile, although it does not appear on my other user profiles and Safari there is unaffected.

How do I remove it so that I can continue to use Safari under that profile?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same thing. Force-quit Safari and reopen it, immediately pressing the command & period keys to stop the page from loading. If you're quick about it, that should do it.